# Glade editor not showing icons in palette

Tags: windows-xp, gtk, glade

I've just installed the GTK+ Glade 3.6.7 designer on Windows XP and there are no icons in the palette.  I can select small icons or large icons from the view menu but neither will show.  I just get red X images. The toolbar icons do show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. You can file a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glade3).